# How do I properly Add/Remove a Select Option and Hide/Show a Div?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to manage user roles using a select list; any roles selected will be visible under the select list and the option is removed from the select list.  I'm using a custom data tag on my div so I can reference each individual "display", and using jQuery to hide/unhide each "display" as well as add/remove the option from the select list.  However, my application crashes my browser while testing this feature. The crashing is inconsistent; sometimes, it happens after adding or removing a few roles, and other times, it only happens after prolonged use.

jQuery (1.8.3)

```
//remove role, add option
$(".role_display .close").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $("[data-bvalue='" + $(this).data("hvalue") + "']").hide();
        $("#selectedRole_" + $(this).data("hvalue") + "_").val(false);
        $("#User_Roles").append("<option value=" + $(this).data("hvalue") + "></option>");
        $("#User_Roles option[value=" + $(this).data("hvalue") + "]").text($(this).data("tvalue"));
        $("#User_Roles option[value=" + $(this).data("hvalue") + "]").removeAttr("selected");                
    });
});
//add role, remove option
$(".role_add").click(function () {
    $("[data-bvalue='" + $("#User_Roles").val() + "']").show();
    $("#selectedRole_" + $("#User_Roles").val() + "_").val(true);
    $("#User_Roles option[value=" + $("#User_Roles").val() + "]").remove();
    $("#User_Roles option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
});
```

HTML - Select List (empty/no options if all roles are assigned)

```
<select class="form-control" id="User_Roles" name="User.Roles">
</select>
```

HTML - Select List (only has options not currently assigned)

```
<select class="form-control" id="User_Roles" name="User.Roles">
    <option value="1">Admin</option>
    <option value="2">Staff</option>
</select>
```

HTML - Display (a loop builds each one of these for each role in a pre-defined list; if it's been assigned to the user, the "_selectedRole" option is true, else is false)

```
<div class="btn btn-default col-lg-12 role_display hidden" data-bvalue="@role.RoleId">
    <div class="pull-left">
        @role.Name
        @Html.Hidden("_role[" + role.RoleId + "]", role.RoleId)
        @Html.Hidden("_selectedRole[" + role.RoleId + "]", false)
    </div>
    <div class="close" data-hvalue="@role.RoleId" data-tvalue="@role.Name">&times;/div>
</div>
```

Again, the code works, it just crashes randomly while adding or removing roles.  Is there anything wrong with the way I have this set up?

Comment: suggest you make a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates issue

Comment: Which version of browser you use? Does the error disappear, if you upgrade to the latest version of jquery? Did you try assigning different IDs to two select-elements? Did it affect frequency of the error? Which test tool you use?

Comment: I redid my code; added an id to the hidden input for true/false, and instead of using .show()/.hide(), I used .addClass("hidden") and .removeClass("hidden")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you crashed, but here are some things I see:

(1) When you concatenate the string for the new `<option>` element, you are not surrounding the value of the "value" attribute with quotes.

---

(2) There appears to be no reason to have the following line, since the newly added option is not selected anyway:

```
$("#User_Roles option[value=" + $(this).data("hvalue") + "]").removeAttr("selected");
```

---

(3) A more efficient and parsimonious way to add the new option would be:

```
$('<option value="' + $(this).data("hvalue") + '"></option>').text($(this).data("tvalue")).appendTo('#User_Roles');
```

In general, you should completely build the new element and then append it.

---

(4) Instead of unselecting an option like this:

```
$("#User_Roles option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

You should do this:

```
$("#User_Roles option:selected").prop("selected", false);
```

---

(5) You are missing a `<` for the closing `</div>` on the following line:

```
<div class="close" data-hvalue="@role.RoleId" data-tvalue="@role.Name">&times;/div>
```

Comment: This helped, but I also added an id to the hidden input for true/false, and instead of using .show()/.hide(), I used .addClass("hidden") and .removeClass("hidden")